# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON - NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am working with nodejs and typescript. When trying to query my database it returns the following error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>       --> starting at object with constructor 'Query'
>       |     property '_timer' -> object with constructor 'Timer'
>       --- property '_object' closes the circle
>       at JSON.stringify ()
>       at stringify

[image]

This is my code.

```
 public async list (req: Request, res: Response) {
     const list = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM projects');

     res.json(list);
 }
```

Comment: Welcome / Benvenido.  We work in English on Stack Overflow.  Please ask spanish-language questions on https://es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us your relevant `import` or `require()` statements. Plain old [npm mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) does't work with `async`.

Comment: Please add your project model / schema with your question.